# Efficient Implementation of Dynamic Snake-Like Body in UE5: Seeking Advice on Optimized Approach

Tags: shaders, performance, graphics-programming, unreal-5

Platforms: iOS, Android, and PC.
I want to implement a snake body that can dynamically grow in length, narrow, and bend (simulate body movement, similar to bending in an arc).
I'm using UE5, and initially, I used components where each body part was a spline mesh. However, this approach proved to be resource-intensive, resulting in numerous draw calls.
I aim to find a more efficient solution, possibly leveraging vertex shaders. However, I lack the necessary experience and don't know how to approach the decision-making process to find a solution for my idea.
Does anyone know how this can be implemented? Please share your advice!

Comment: I remember seeing a concept game in UE that used the rope physics to simulate the snake body. Might be able to find it on youtube.

Comment: Can you share any more details about the kinds of movements the snake will perform? Is it something like the classic 2D game snake or the 3D game Snake Pass where the player is mostly just steering the head, and the body flows through the points the head has traversed like a thread following a needle? Or does this snake move like a sidewinder, or something else?